# Log4net Запись в разные файлы в зависимости от логгера

Tags: c#, .net, логирование, log4net

Есть задача, которую не могу с ходу решить.
Нужно с помощью библиотеки log4net реализовать логеры для неких объектов. Они должны записывать информацию в свой файл, т.е. если имя объекта равно "ТЕСТ1", то записывать в ТЕСТ1.txt

Сейчас это якобы делается так:

```
var root = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

var layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("[%date{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}] %thread %-14logger %-5level - %message%newline%exception");
layout.ActivateOptions();

var appender = new log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender()
{
Name = this.Name,
File = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Const.LogsPath, this.Name + ".log"),
MaxSizeRollBackups = 2,
MaximumFileSize = "20MB",
AppendToFile = true,
LockingModel = new log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock(),
Layout = layout,
Threshold = Level.All,
};
appender.ActivateOptions();

root.Root.AddAppender(appender);
root.Configured = true;

logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.Name);
```

Почему якобы? Потому что если есть 8 объектов, то каждый записывает во все файлы: ТЕСТ1 записывает в ТЕСТ1.txt, ТЕСТ2.txt и т.д.

Как реализовать это? Буду рад или готовому решению или направлению куда копать.

P.S. Сам необоснованно думаю, что нужно каждому объекту свой репозиторий создать, но это нужно обдумать.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();

            var file1 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".log");
            var log1 = InitialiseLogToFile(file1);
            log1.Info("logger1 info");
            log1.Error("logger1 error");

            var file2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".log");
            var log2 = InitialiseLogToFile(file2);
            log2.Info("logger2 info");
            log2.Error("logger2 error");
        }

        private static ILog InitialiseLogToFile(string file)
        {
            var hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository();

            var patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            var appender = new FileAppender { File = file, AppendToFile = true, Layout = patternLayout };
            appender.ActivateOptions();

            var logger = (Logger)hierarchy.GetLogger(file);
            logger.AddAppender(appender);
            hierarchy.Configured = true;

            return LogManager.GetLogger(file);
        }
    }
}
```